# How to SQL question about midnight interaction

Tags: t-sql

When looking for transactions WHERE Date_time between Date_1 01-01-2019 and Date_2 12-31-2019, will midnight(12:05AM) transactions from 12-31-2019 show on result?*

Comment: If you mean will a row with the value `2019-12-31 00:05:00` will show when you use `BETWEEN '20190101' AND '20191231' then the answer is: No. `2019-12-31 00:05:00` is **after** `2019-12-31` as as a date and time value it would be `2019-12-31 00:00:00`. Use explicit date boundaries with `>=` and `<`.

Comment: What database are you using? On SQL Server it would not since it assumes time of 12:00 AM when you do not provide it.

Comment: The OP has tagged [tag:tsql], @Isaac , so SQL Server or it's much older "sibling" Sybase.

Comment: @Larnu, I should have known that. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
-- How to SQL question about midnight interaction
select * from mytable_06_17

select * from mytable_06_17 
where myDateTime between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
```

Between operator consider the maximum value as '2019-12-31 00:00:00.000' any value greater than this value will not be part of the output.